# How to save a figure generated from missingno (python) to visualize missing values?

Tags: python

I want to save the figure generated from missingno package. The plot is generated by `msno.matrix(df)`:

[image]

I tried:

```
fig = msno.matrix(df)
fig.save_fig('plot.png')
```

but it doesn't work. I received the following message:

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'

Comment: Try to replace `fig.save_fig('plot.png')` with this, `fig_copy = fig.get_figure()` followed by `fig_copy.savefig('plot.png')`, HTH.

Comment: I have tried to improve the appearance of your question by a but a reformatting, embedding the image and shortening the title.

Answer (score 8):

as @user2977071 added in the comment, it should help by also adding bbox_inches in order to save whole figure.

```
fig = msno.matrix(df)
fig_copy = fig.get_figure()
fig_copy.savefig('plot.png', bbox_inches = 'tight')
```